# Couldn't load hardware-print from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader when set as system app

Tags: android

The app works fine when I run as non system app. When I make it a system app(using [this](http://howto.highonandroid.com/android-how-to-tutorials/how-to-install-user-apps-as-system-apps-on-your-android/)) I get this error:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load hardware-print from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/com.prematix.itc-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null`

I already have the `libhardware-print.so` in `src/main/jniLibs`. I get error in this line:

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("hardware-print");
}
```

It works as non-system app. Please help

Comment: same problem with me. have you find solution?

Comment: @user2290351. i dont think i found the solution. im sorry

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your gradle file under default config

ndk
{
  abiFilters "The package name under jniLibs" 
}

In my case package name was "armeabi"

Comment: hey.. you are from hosur? I am too! Wait..do you work at prematix?